# How to compare two times from datetime package

Tags: datetime

I have this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\begin{document}
\currenttime
\par
\formattime{18}{0}{0} 
\end{document}
```

and want to compare these times if the time is before or after 18 o clock.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `datetime` you can print times; if you want an expandable test for times here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter

\newif\iftim@seconds
\@ifpackageloaded{datetime}
  {\@ifundefined{pdfcreationdate}\tim@secondsfalse\tim@secondstrue}
  {\ifdefined\pdfcreationdate\tim@secondstrue\fi}

\newcommand{\comparetime}[6]{%
  % #1=hour, #2=minutes, #3=seconds
  % #4=code if time is before current time
  % #5=code if time is equal to current time
  % #6=code if time is after current time
  \ifcase\pdf@strcmp{\tim@giventime{#1}{#2}{#3}}{\tim@currenttime}
    #5% case 0
  \or
    #6% case 1
  \else
    #4% case -1
  \fi
}

\iftim@seconds
  \def\tim@currenttime{%
    \expandafter\tim@currenttime@aux\pdfcreationdate\@nil
  }
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\tim@currenttime@aux\string D:#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9\@nil{%
    \tim@currenttime@auxi#9\@nil
  }
  \def\tim@currenttime@auxi#1#2#3#4#5#6#7\@nil{%
    \number\numexpr #1#2*3600+#3#4*60+#5#6\relax
  }
  \def\tim@giventime#1#2#3{\number\numexpr#1*3600+#2*60+#3\relax}
\else
  \def\tim@currenttime{\number\time}
  \def\tim@giventime#1#2#3{\number\numexpr#1*60+#2\relax}
\fi

\begin{document}

\currenttime

\comparetime{15}{14}{0}{before}{equal}{after}

\comparetime{15}{40}{0}{before}{equal}{after}

\end{document}
```

The code is independent of `datetime` and it works with all engines; however, with XeLaTeX, seconds are not available so times that differ only for the seconds part are considered to be equal.

The example was compiled at the shown time (which is the only reason for loading `datetime`).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The seconds are irrelevant because TeX knows only minutes from midnight when it is executed, no seconds. This information is stored in `\time` primitive register. I created the `\giventime` macro which is similar to mentioned `\formattime`, but the third parameter (seconds) is simply ignored.

```
\newcount\minutes
\def\giventime#1#2#3{\minutes=#1 \multiply\minutes by60 \advance\minutes by#2 }

\giventime{18}{59}{0}

\ifnum\time<\minutes Current time is before given \fi
\ifnum\time=\minutes Current time is in the same minute as given \fi
\ifnum\time>\minutes Current time is after given \fi
```

Note, there is no `@` in my macros :-)

**Edit** My solution shows that if we know what is desired and we know TeX primitives then the solution could be much more simple and straghtforward than using LaTeX packages. Using `datetime`, you must compare two strings and the solution includes complicated macros like in the accepted answer. Using TeX primitives you are comparing simply two numbers.