# Less-than string comparison like \ifstrequal

Tags: etoolbox

Is there a way of getting an `\ifstrlessthan` command that works similarly to [etoobox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox?lang=en)'s `\ifstrequal`?  I want to do something like

```
\ifstrlessthan{\creationdate}{2017-01-01}%
  {Old company name}{New company name}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))! Do you mean something like [this: How to compare two times from datetime package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196513/124842) With date instead time?

Comment: I looked in the xstring package, but couldn't find anything.  Perhaps this is partly why LaTeX uses a separate program to alphabetize indexes.

Comment: Why do you want to use strings for that? You can split this up and then compare numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\newcommand{\companyNameChangeDate}{2016-01-01}
\newcommand{\creationDate}{2017-01-01}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\ifcase\pdf@strcmp{\creationDate}{\companyNameChangeDate} new company name \or new company name \else old company name \fi
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

prints *new company name*

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the hyphens, you get numbers that can be compared:

```
\documentclass{article}

% assume dates are in ISO format YYYY-MM-DD
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifdateearlierTF}[2]{%
  \ifnum\@date@to@number{#1}<\@date@to@number{#2}
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\def\@date@to@number#1{\expandafter\@date@to@number@aux\romannumeral-`Q#1\@nil}
\def\@date@to@number@aux#1-#2-#3\@nil{#1#2#3}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\creationdate}{2016-01-01}
\ifdateearlierTF{\creationdate}{2017-01-01}{Old company name}{New company name}

\renewcommand{\creationdate}{2017-06-30}
\ifdateearlierTF{\creationdate}{2017-01-01}{Old company name}{New company name}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I can only accept one answer, and I've accepted Benjamin's because it's marginally simpler and a more general solution, but this is a good answer too.